# How to adjust the column width to the content of a cell and allow to modify the width in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe7

Good morning, I'm trying to adjust the width of the columns of a grid to its content but I also need that width can be modified manually. The grid is a TStringGrid and im using delphi XE7.
I am trying to do it with the following code:

```
procedure gDetailDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  vWidth : Integer;
begin
  if (FormPosition.WMaximized = True) then
  begin
    vWidth := gDetail.Canvas.TextWidth(gDetail.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
    if vWidth > aColWidthExpanded[ACol] then
      aColWidthExpanded[ACol] := vWidth+20;
    gDetail.ColWidths[ACol] := aColWidthExpanded[ACol];
  end;
end;
```

The grid loads correctly and the column widths are correctly adjusted to the content, but I cant modify the column width manually. What am I doing wrong that I cant modify the column width

Comment: What is a TStringAlignGrid? It is not a component delivered with Delphi.

Comment: Really I don't know, but i thought it was a delphi component, maybe it's a TStringGrid.

Comment: Please check your source code and edit your question to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify the column width in the `OnDrawCell` event. When you change the width manually, you trigger the `OnDrawCell` which change the width back to the content. In short, you can't do both!

Comment: A drawing event is meant only for drawing! DO NOT manipulate UI state in a drawing event, use the current state as-is. In this case, manipulate the cell widths only when the Form is loaded, or at least when the data is loaded into the grid.  Then don't touch the widths anymore, let the user resize them as needed.